# How to add News Letter Subscription checkbox on checkout Success Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email, ajax, newsletter, checkbox

I am getting email address in the database with this function:

```
protected $subscriberFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    ...code...
    )
    {
     $this->subscriberFactory= $subscriberFactory;
     ....code....
    }

public function subscribeNewsLetter($email)
     {

        $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);

     }
```

In my template file, calling it as:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" onClick="<?php $block- 
>subscribeNewsLetter($email); ?>">Subscribe to News Letter</button>r<br>
   <script>
      function subscribeNewsLetter($email)
          {
            alert("subscribeNewsLetter");
          }
  </script>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem here is, when I refresh the page function subscrieNewsLetter()  is executed before checking the checkbox. Even checkbox is not checked, the email address gets stored in database.

I find some examples for this using AJAX like:
https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-newsletter-subscription-via-ajax/ but it is bit different form my problem. I know magetions will find a more smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by following this aproach:

https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-jquery-ajax-request/